# Can you name properties through a Struct's/Class's constructor?

Tags: vb.net, properties, structure, unions, bit-fields

I've done some looking around on this subject and haven't really been able to find much on it.  In fact, I'm pretty sure I already know the answer to this one, but I'm going to ask just in case there's some advanced technique I'm unaware of. (which has a fairly high probability)  Can you declare the names of a structure's/class's properties or at least rename them through a constructor of some sort?

Basically, long story short I'm trying to create a union-structure that effectively gives you bitfield style flags but gives you the ability to specify names for the flags at declaration to make the code a bit cleaner looking.   I know you do the same kind of thing in C by making a union of an integer(char/double/whatever) and a structure of bitfields.  Something that I could basically do this:

```
    Public status as BitField({"PowerOn","Ready","Error",...})
```

And the basic structure would look like:

```
    Public Structure (or Class) BitField
        Private _value as UInt16

        Public Property value as UInt16
            Get
                Return _value
            End Get
            Set(input as UInt16)
                _value = input
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property bit0 As Boolean
            Get
                Return ((_value And &H1UI) > 0)
            End Get
            Set(input as Boolean)
                If input Then
                    _value = _value Or &H1UI
                Else
                    _value = _value And &HFFFEUI
                End If
            End Set
        End Property

     (and so on for bit 1 through 15)

        Public Sub New(ByVal names() As String)
            ...Something that redeclairs/renames/equates "bit0" with names(0)...

            ...Something that redeclairs/renames/equates "bit1" with names(1)...
            and so on

        End Sub
    End Structure/Class
```

And after that I could call status.Error to get or set the third bit, but if I wanted to I could just compare status.value to a mask to check for a certain state.

I mean I know in C you'd just do:

```
    union {
        unsigned int value;
        struct {
            unsigned PowerOn:1;
            unsigned Ready:1;
            unsigned Error:1;
            ...
        };
    } status;
```

But I'd like to get that same level of "cleanliness" in my code and not have to have a huge declaration that I have to copy and half rewrite every time I want to use it.

Like I said at the beginning, I'm assuming that I'm way off base and there is no way to do what I'm proposing in VB.Net, but if anyone has any thoughts I'd love to hear them.

Comment: How would the code compile if it did know the actual names of the properties until runtime?  You could use an pseudo indexer and an enum so that in one case Bit0 maps to Foo, in another it maps to Bar.  Of course the simpler approach would be to use save the bool rather than en/decoding a bit

Comment: You could also use inheritance to change what each part means and where it maps to for each new use

Comment: @Plutonix The main reason I am trying to do this is I'm having to interface with an embedded system and decode data transmissions from it.  A lot of the fields are just bytes or ints but there are several that are bitmaped and are used to determine what fields are present in the message and which ones are skipped.  So I have to read in a byte and then check flags to see which fields are next in the message.

Comment: Consider a base class which handles the core of it; then each class which inherits from it could provide the Foo==>0  Bar==>1 type xlatations

Comment: Wait, can you do something like: Public Property flagField = bit0   inside the subclass that would make status.flagField point to the bit0 property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant create or rename properties at runtime because the compiler needs to know what they are.  Based on comments, here is one way to create a different `BitSetter` object with different meanings or maps for each *with a minimum of new code*:

```
Public Class BitSetter(Of T)
    Private value As UInt16
    Public Sub New(v As UInt16)
        value = v
    End Sub

    Public Sub SetBit(n As T, b As Boolean)
        ' do stuff
    End Sub

    Public Function GetBit(n As T) As Boolean
        ' do stuff
    End Function
End Class
```

- I am not sure what the reason is for the `Boolean input` param is, but I would break that off into its own method for clarity.
- As shown the base value can only be assigned when creating a new object.  This may or may not be a good idea.  A `SetValue(n As UInt16)` method is another way to set it.
- Turn on `Option Strict`; code such as `value = value Or &H1UI` includes an implicit conversion and wont compile.

Making the class generic `(Of T)` will allow you to define a different set of semantics for each varietal:

```
Private Enum FooBits
    Flag
    [Error]
    Green
    '...
End Enum

Private Enum BarBits
    Red = 0
    Charm = 1
    Quark = 3
    Ziggy = 4
End Enum
```

In case you arent aware, `Flag` would be for Bit(0), `Error` for 1 etc, so go in order or be explicit.  The second set gives them explicit values and rather than defining something like a [Reserved] which should not be used, it just skips that value so it *cant* be used.  Creating and using them:

```
' starting value of 3:
Dim fooB As New BitSetter(Of FooBits)(3)
Dim barB As New BitSetter(Of BarBits)(6)       ' value = 6

Dim b As Boolean
b = fooB.GetBit(FooBits.Error)

barB.SetBit(BarBits.Quark, True)
```

The `FooBits` version will only allow members of the `FooBits Enum` to be used with its methods.  The Type is enforced and it is clear in code which bit/item is being used.  Trying to use a member of `BarBits` with `fooB` (using Option Strict) will result in a compile error.  It would also prevent passing a magic number value:

```
barB.SetBit(2, True)
```

So for each new part or map, the only new code you need would be for a new `Enum` set (and `BitSetter` instance).

If you want to make it more succinct (e.g. `b = barB.Get(BarBits.Ziggy)`) you will need to escape the method names in the class since they are keywords:

```
Public Sub [Set](n As T, b As Boolean)

Public Function [Get](n As T) As Boolean
```